# Pandas datetime issue

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a **.csv** file with the following info:

```
- id
- values
- date
```

I would like to search with dataframe, but I am unable to do it:

```
val = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
val['date'] = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(date) for date in val['date']])

selData = val[val['date'].month == 1]
```

I receive the following error:

```
Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a dataframe column is a datetime column, you access the date functionality with the `dt` accessor.

```
selData = val[val['date'].dt.month == 1]
```

---

Also, this should've been how you read your file

```
val = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

selData = val[val['date'].month == 1]
```

Or

```
val = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
val['date'] = pd.to_datetime(val['date'])

selData = val[val['date'].month == 1]
```